# Nested text-align in html

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` element which I would like to be aligned to the right of the page. For example,

```
<div class="meta">
     Answered May 12 '20 at 14:32 <br />
     <div class="author">Person A</div>
</div>

.meta {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Which looks like this:

```
                                                Answered May 12 '20 at 14:32
                                                                    Person A
```

Now, I would like the `.author` div to be aligned left within `.meta` div, to look like this:

```
                                                Answered May 12 '20 at 14:32
                                                Person A
```

So I added this:

```
.author {
    text-align: left;
}
```

But it resulted in this:

```
                                                Answered May 12 '20 at 14:32
Person A
```

What style should I use to achieve the above effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because your `.author` div is 100% width because its parent is a block element.

So to solve this wrap your `.meta` div inside an another div i.e `.wrap` and then apply `text-align:right`. Also you will need to apply `display:inline-block` to the `.meta` div so that it can take only its content width not `100%`.

```css
.wrap {
  text-align: right;
}

.meta {
  display: inline-block;
}

.author {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="meta">
    Answered May 12 '20 at 14:32 <br />
    <div class="author">Person A</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Simple solution is this.

CSS

```
.meta {
    text-align: right;     
}
.title{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="meta">
    <div class="title">
     Answered May 12 '20 at 14:32 <br>
     <div class="author">Person A</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```css
.meta {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="meta">
  Answered May 12 '20 at 14:32 <br />
  <div class="author">Person A</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution #1. Use flex.

```css
.meta {
  display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="meta">
    <div class="title">
     Answered May 12 '20 at 14:32 <br>
     <div class="author">Person A</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Solution #2. Align text to left(default) and add left margin to align to align div to right side.

```css
.meta {
    margin-left: 75%;
}
```

```html
<div class="meta">
     Answered May 12 '20 at 14:32 <br />
     <div class="author">Person A</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="meta" style="float: right;">
    Answered May 12 '20 at 14:32
    <div class="author">Person A</div>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Comment: **Remember**: You've to use **Clearfix** hack for floating.

Answer (score -2):

i think you can do like this

`<div align="right">`

search in this link
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_p_align.asp

Comment: They imply, but don’t say it strongly enough: the `align` attribute is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. This is why w3schools is less than ideal source.

Answer (score -2):

i think you can do like this 
 `<div align="right">`
searsh in this link 
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_p_align.asp

Comment: Why have you posted this three times?